# Current calculation for circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement

I am new to this field and need help calculating current I2 through voltage source 2.

U1=1V

U2=3V

R=10 Ohm

Unfortunately I have no clue how to calculate this. 
Would be so thankful for help!
[image]

Comment: What do you know how to do, exactly? (Can't build on no foundation at all.)

Comment: Start by reading on Kirchhoff's laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws. The wikipedia even includes an example. This question will soon be closed due to lack of effort shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the transformations below. They are not difficult ones. (If they are, you are not at all ready.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgFR9c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You should be able to solve the FINAL STEP version for the current in the resistor marked "2*R". That will be the current you are looking for and you should be able to see why, as well.

Comment: thank you jonk, i will try!